# What mission gives the most money the fastest?

Tags: payday-2

In Payday 2, I am trying to go Infamous. To do so, I need 200 million dollars in my offshore account. What mission can I do to get the most amount of money the fastest?

If it is the same mission across all difficulties, then tell me which mission. If it is different across all of the difficulties, tell me which missions at which difficulty.

I pretty much play solo in public lobbies and am still trying to learn stealth, so levels that require coordination and stealth are hard for me.

Comment: Do slaughterhouse on overkill, gives 8mil in the end I think. Undercover is also a great one to complete.

Comment: If you know the code, unlock the hidden Overdrill safe in the First World Bank on Death Wish or higher.  Each run requires a 2000 second drill (not affected by drill skills), so will take about 36 to 40 minutes, but gives you just over $40 million (before loot skills / Team boosts) in gold bars, which add on to a base payout of $6.5 million and $2 million in ATMs/loose cash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose there is one true statistic to this, but it is going to depend on your skill. I would do the following:

On this [Steam Post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/218620/discussions/8/617328415072133913/), which I agree with, many players say to do the **Shadow Raid**.  The thing is, you need 4 people that you can coordinate with (something public matches don't really allow).

> You need a 4-person team, and it won't work with pubs. You have to know exactly what you are doing and where you are going, and everybody needs full ECM

I've never tried this tactic, but from the sounds of it and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wImz-_RMO6k), you play on the hardest difficulty (**Deathwish** for console versions, or **One Down** if you can handle it), go loud, and have your ECMs at the ready.  Kill anyone you run into, and place an ECM when needed to prevent the 1 minute remaining alarm. You'll earn around ~$13 million each time in about 5 minutes.

---

For **Solo** games here are some options:

- **Mallcrasher Overkill or Deathwish**.
  For this mission, you'll want a saw to be able to break into all the ATMs quickly.  You'll need an ammo bag as well to replenish saw blades. You can cause the 50,000 dollars of damage pretty fast with a few well placed grenades to end the mission. There is also a jewelry store which you can loot for some more money.
- **Hoxton Breakout Overkill**.  This one gives a nice payout at the end, though it's not very fast as it is a 2 day job. <s>The **Pro job version** also grants more money, but obviously carries the risk of not being able to restart.</s> I don't recommend doing this one on Deathwish or higher as it can be pretty difficult soloing.
- **The Diamond Store on Deathwish or One Down**.  You'll want to take a "Control Freak" route, and use ECMs.  This can be pretty profitable and fast. [You may be even able to stealth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ghKIIUnJlE4) it fast if done carefully enough by controlling the crowds and taking out the Guards.

Comment: this answers my question (before i had just finishing thinking of rivisions in the shower), so im gonna update the question

Comment: It is enough to get 3 ppl crew, or even 2 ppl. You just need to find all lootable stuff in warehouse.

Comment: Pro job versions? Not any more dude, they went away a couple of updates back. For me, I'd farm Boiling Point and Aftershock, circa $10m in around 15-20ms, easy to play loud missions with internet randoms.

Comment: @Bonus I'm stuck on Console version where they still exist (at least they did last month when I last played!)  I wish the Console version was as up to date as PC.  So much more content to play still...

Comment: Oh aye, sorry, I'd only been thinking of the PC version, hadn't considered what platform might be in use

Comment: @Bonus Yea us console heisters don't have the Boiling Point heist if I'm right.  We do have Aftershock though (as part of the free update that came out a few months ago).  I believe Console heisters have everything the PC game has up to the end of 2015.

Comment: Diamond store stealth/speed is the most efficient in my experience, playing on console with one co-op buddy. I believe you can literally finish it in under a minute, if speed is what youre going for.

Comment: Also hardest difficulty is now One Down. If you go stealth One down is the way to go not deathwish anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Keep doing the big bank at the difficulty that gives 2million and slaughterhouse on the difficulty that gives 2million for variety. However, I believe the big bank is easier at the 2,000,000 difficulty.

Comment: That's over 100 runs, that's insane

Comment: Not as insane as doing lower difficulty :D